# Has anyone tried proving that any of Hilbert's open problems are independent of chosen axioms?

Tags: set-theory

I had just begun learning about set theory and I was wondering - especially after searching Gödel's incompleteness theorem - whether anyone tried proving that any of Hilbert's OPEN (i.e. unsolved, as of 2018) problems are independent of some chosen axioms (e.g. ZFC), like the Continuum Hypothesis?

Edit: I am asking specifically for those problems that are still unresolved, e.g. 8th, 12th, or 16th.

Comment: Well, famously the continuum hypothesis

Comment: Are there other problems in ZFC, which are like the continuum hypothesis and can neither be proven or claimed to be false? Did most examples for such statements arose from mathematical logic and set theory?

Comment: @Cornman Most, yes. But not all, by far. Several problems first considered in analysis, algebra, topology, have turned out to be independent.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo could you elaborate as an answer? If no one answers my question in some weeks I'll select yours as an answer.